# Can't connect to wifi on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

i recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8.1, but cannot connect to WiFi form Ubuntu.  The WiFi router is not listed as an option in the dropdown menu, but is clearly working because I can connect to it when using Windows.  I have read countless Q and A's similar to this, but unfortunately none of the solutions that people provided worked for me.  Thanks to whoever answers this!

Comment: post the output of `lspci |grep Network`.

Comment: And output of `rfkill list wifi`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7009121/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7009133/

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me occasionally.

Running `iwlist wlan0 scan` solves the problem for me.  Replace wlan0 with whatever your wireless device is.

Comment: by wireless device do you mean the name of the connection?  sorry if that is an obvious question